# Neo4j: Creating Multiple Relationships Not Working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am creating multiple relationships in one query. If a match is not found for the first relationship the second one is not created. If both matches exist then both relationships work.

Example:

Assume that 'MATCH1ID' below does not exist but 'MATCH2ID' does. Why does this happen?

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
MERGE (NewRecord:OBJECTNAME { Id: 'ABZDEFG' })
SET NewRecord.name='NEWNAME'
WITH NewRecord
MATCH (a)
WHERE a.Id = 'MATCH1ID'
CREATE (a)-[ar:Relationship1]->(NewRecord)
WITH NewRecord MATCH (b)
WHERE b.Id = 'MATCH2ID'
CREATE (b)-[br:Relationship2]->(NewRecord)
```

(If I switch the order of the node that does exist to be first in the order it works)

**WORKS**

```
MERGE (NewRecord:OBJECTNAME { Id: 'ABZDEFG' })
SET NewRecord.name='NEWNAME'
WITH NewRecord
MATCH (b)
WHERE b.Id = 'MATCH2ID'
CREATE (b)-[br:Relationship2]->(NewRecord)
WITH NewRecord
MATCH (a)
WHERE a.Id = 'MATCH1ID'
CREATE (a)-[ar:Relationship1]->(NewRecord)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a [OPTIONAL MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/optional-match/) instead of a simple `MATCH`:

```
MERGE (NewRecord:OBJECTNAME { Id: 'ABZDEFG' })
SET NewRecord.name='NEWNAME'
WITH NewRecord
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)
WHERE a.Id = 'MATCH1ID'

FOREACH(x IN (CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END) | 
    CREATE (a)-[ar:Relationship1]->(NewRecord)
)

WITH NewRecord
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)
WHERE b.Id = 'MATCH2ID'

FOREACH(x IN (CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END) | 
    CREATE (b)-[br:Relationship2]->(NewRecord) 
)
```

Also, this query uses a trick with `FORACH` and `CASE WHEN` to handle conditions. In this case, the `CREATE` statement is executed only when `a` or `b` variables are not null.

See [Neo4j: LOAD CSV - Handling Conditionals](https://dzone.com/articles/neo4j-load-csv-handling).