# Neo4j - creating multiple relationships with FOREACH/CASE WHEN trick, and then return number of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am creating a node, and creating relationships between it and a bunch of different existing nodes at the same time. Some of the other nodes may not exist, so I am using the FOREACH/CASE WHEN trick described [here by neo4j staff](https://community.neo4j.com/t/can-you-set-cypher-lenient-create-relationship-true-in-aura/18800/10) and also [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060772/2782092).

I'd like to return the count of each relationship that were created, but I can't pull that out of the FOREACH. My current query is something like:

```
CREATE (p:Paper {title: $title})
WITH p
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:Author) WHERE a.name IN $a_names
OPTIONAL MATCH (p2:Paper) WHERE p2.title IN $citee_titles
OPTIONAL MATCH (p3:Paper) WHERE p3.title IN $citer_titles
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN [1] END | MERGE (a)-[:AUTHORED]->(p))
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN p2 IS NOT NULL THEN [1] END | MERGE (p)-[:CITES]->(p2))
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN p3 IS NOT NULL THEN [1] END | MERGE (p3)-[:CITES]->(p))
```

Any of `$a_names`, `$citee_titles` or `$citer_titles` can be an empty set or have no elements matching any existing nodes.

I have tried adding a WITH and additional MATCHes on the end, something like:

```
WITH p, a, p2, p3
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r1:AUTHORED]->(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[r2:CITES]->(p2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p3)-[r3:CITES]->(p)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT r1), COUNT(DISTINCT r2), COUNT(DISTINCT r3)
```

It works, but runs into the original problem that the FOREACH solution was trying to solve - if there are no matches for `r1` then I don't get results for `r2` and `r3`.

Any thoughts on how to deal with this? My goal is to test that the number of relationships created matches what I expect based on the parameters passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you are trying to create the relationships with the newly created paper node, which is `p`. Since, there is only one `p` node, to get the count of each type of node created by the `FOREACH` statement, you can simply return the count of distinct `a`, `p2`, `p3` nodes matched by the filters, like this

```
CREATE (p:Paper {title: $title})
WITH p
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:Author) WHERE a.name IN $a_names
OPTIONAL MATCH (p2:Paper) WHERE p2.title IN $citee_titles
OPTIONAL MATCH (p3:Paper) WHERE p3.title IN $citer_titles
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN [1] END | MERGE (a)-[:AUTHORED]->(p))
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN p2 IS NOT NULL THEN [1] END | MERGE (p)-[:CITES]->(p2))
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN p3 IS NOT NULL THEN [1] END | MERGE (p3)-[:CITES]->(p))
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT a), COUNT(DISTINCT p2), COUNT(DISTINCT p3)
```

Comment: I think I convinced myself that this might not always give the right answer, but I guess there's no way that COUNT(DISTINCT a) wouldn't equal COUNT(DISTINCT r1)